# Is there a way to output the data from emmeans() into a clean table format?

Tags: r, datatable, export, emmeans

I want to make a table from the means and contrasts from the emmeans() function in R. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your dataset, desired output and the code you have tried so far (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Use `as.data.frame()` and then whatever else you want to put it in the form you want. There is also an `xtable` method that preserves the annotations. It’s all documented.